# TypeScript: how to "import" js and other ts ressources/modules without have them merged in the emitted js file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I read the Typescript Handbook and searched quite a bit but I still cannot find the proper way to do that: use existing js files as reference in my ts files and not have them in the emitted js file.

For instance, let's say my structure is like this in my web project:

```
- js/
   - old-lib.js
     - app-output.js
     - new-lib-output.js

- app-src/
   - newLib/
     - my-lib.ts
     - tsconfig.json
   - app/
     - my-app.ts
     - tsconfig.json
```

In my-app.ts file, I have something like this:

```
namespace App
{
    export class MyApp
    {
      ... some logic which requires existing code from my old-lib.js file.
  }
}
```

So if I use a triple-slash reference to the said js file, my output file is gonna include the source lib file as well. How do I get rid of that? I understand I can create and Interface to map declare the types and functions contained in my old js but is there a better way?

Also, following the same principle, I want to use a new lib (with different functions of course) and have it compiled separately (new-lib-output.js and app-output.js). Everywhere I look I see examples of modules importation but nobody talks about the exported js as in all examples it seems the output is all together in the same file.

My goal is to be able to reuse js files in different contexts, now always with my app but with other apps.

Thanks for any help you could provide!!

Comment: Reuse the ts files? I dont see any benefit in seperating the resulting js into multiple files.

Comment: I'm curious how do you expect your code to even run if the parts your code relies on isn't in your bundle? If you need "some generic interface" that will resolve in global namespace, then I guess your first order of business is to ensure you don't import at all, but do something like `LibReference = (globalContext.LibYouNeed) ? globalcontext.LibYouNeed : { /* function stubs for everything you call */ }` or something and then always make sure to test it in a context that already has the lib you need loaded in-context.

Comment: The resulting js files are to be imported in the same web page. The idea is to get different "apps" to use the same libraries. The 2 "apps" will actually be 2 different pages but they use the same libs, which can be cached and reused among different pages in the site. That's not a new concept to me, the web is built that way! So you are telling me that I should just package my 2 apps with 2 copies of the exact same code?? How would that be logical?

Comment: 1. how do you bundle? Webpack, gulp, grunt? 2. do you need types from your old lib? Or are you just using <any> where you need functions/classes from the old lib? If you don't need the types you could just publish your old lib to a cdn and include that in html in your webapps.

Comment: I code all that in Visual Studio and as mentioned, I export the app package in a single file, using outFile:"..." in my tsconfig. As for the typing, I don't really mind since we will be using them but as less as possible. But in any case, my problem is really just about the technicality of the link itself as I want to be able to get a reference in my new ts file without packaging the other libs with my apps. Is that possible?